# How can I use this UndoBar Library in my Android project?

Tags: android

I found this library to make a "undobar" (https://github.com/jenzz/Android-UndoBar), but I do not know how to install it. On some websites I read that I must right click on my project, then go to `Properties-> Java Build Path-> Libraries-> Add External JARs` and select the Zip file that I downloaded, but it's still not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Clone the GitHub project locally to your machine.
2. Import the lib as a project into Eclipse
3. RightKlick on your project in the Package Explorer selecting Properties / Android
4. Under `Library` klick on add and select the lib's project
5. Some aditational OK's should do the trick.

Comment: I can't import the library as a project. It seems like the file its not a library, because it doesnt include a jar file =(. Thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: @Andresaurus What do you mean that you "can't import the library as a project"? What happens when you try?

Comment: After many attempts, I could import the library as a project. I don't really know what I was doing wrong, but with these steps it works.